# How to call short numbers (like 911) on gsm module via AT Command

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, gprs

I use Telit GL865 Module, call to short numbers services. For instance 911, 112, 7000 etc services numbers. 
I can call some telephone form my gsm module via this AT command;

```
ATD+<NUMBER>;
```

example:  ATD+15552224455;

But ATD+911; or ATD+7000 not working. I also tried to add country code at the starting side like,

ATD+1911 (for america) it didnt work.

So how can I do that?

Comment: What SIM is in the module? A regular US cell phone SIM and you're located inside the US?

Comment: SIM is Vodafone SIM. I m located in Turkiye. My country code is 90. I call a cellpohe via this: ATD+905554440099; and it works fine. But I cant call short numbers. Commands are standart in everywhere. Only difference is country code. 1 or 90

Comment: Calling short numbers from abroad won't (usually) work. Since the Turkey emergency number is 112, I'm assuming you're trying to call US 911 from Turkey?

Comment: no no 911 is just an example to understand. Infact I want to call 112 in Turkiye.

Comment: Okay I found it. ATD112; Work for me. Maybe ATD911 work for America too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATD112; works. sim features are important. mine's is vodafone 64kb.

Answer (score 1):

The complete list of emergency numbers is a bit tricky because that it is dependent on (varying) content on the SIM card (EF_ECC).

[11.14](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/1114.htm) says under *6.4.13 SET UP CALL*

> It is possible for the SIM to request the ME to set up an emergency
>   call by supplying the number "112" as called party number. If the SIM
>   supplies a number stored in EF<sub>ECC</sub>, this shall not result in an
>   emergency call.

[22.101](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/22101.htm) says under *10 Emergency Calls*

> Emergency calls shall be supported by the UE without a SIM/USIM/ISIM
>   being present. ... The Home Environment operator shall specify
>   preferred emergency call numbers (e.g. 999 for UK citizens or 110, 118
>   and 119 for Japanese citizens). These emergency call numbers shall be
>   stored in the SIM/USIM and the ME shall read this and use any entry of
>   these digits to set up an emergency call. It shall be possible to
>   store more than one instance of this field.

and under *10.1.1 Identification of emergency numbers*

> The ME shall identify an emergency number dialled by the end user as a
>   valid emergency number and initiate emergency call establishment if it
>   occurs under one or more of the following conditions. If it occurs
>   outside of the following conditions, the ME should not initiate
>   emergency call establishment but normal call establishment. Emergency
>   number identification takes place before and takes precedence over any
>   other (e.g. supplementary service related) number analysis.
>
> > a)    112 and 911 shall always be available. These numbers shall be stored on the ME.
> >
> > b)    Any emergency call number stored on a SIM/USIM when the SIM/USIM is present.
> >
> > c)    000, 08, 110, 999, 118 and 119 when a SIM/USIM is not present. These numbers shall be stored on the ME.
> >
> > d)    Additional emergency call numbers that may have been downloaded by the serving network when the SIM/USIM is present.

So in your case, I think 112 should be the safest bet. You could perhaps try to read and parse EF_ECC with `AT+CRSM` but that is seriously hairy low level SIM stuff...